# Tag proposition: connected-devices

Tags: discussion, tagging

Do we need another tag for questions related to hardware (such as Arduinos, serial communications, IoT devices etc.)? I think we do and created one as kind of *test ballon* a while ago. I named it [connected-devices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connected-devices), added a short tag description and waited for review. Since the review went through I guess at least some users share my view and thus like to propose the tag here on meta. It could for instance be made a synonym of the [hardware](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware)-tag. With WRI pushing their connected devices framework more users might start looking for that name here as well.

Questions where this tag might be appropriate are for example:

- [Uploading sketch to Arduino from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110183/uploading-sketch-to-arduino-from-mathematica)
- [Problem using Arduino with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108776/problem-using-arduino-with-mathematica)
- [Direct Pressure Data Acquisition with Mathematica and Arduino](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101653/direct-pressure-data-acquisition-with-mathematica-and-arduino)
- [Manage a network of Arduinos using Mathematica and xbee](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61413/manage-a-network-of-arduinos-using-mathematica-and-xbee)

Comment: W.r.t "With WRI pushing their connected devices framework", yes I think that this could be a nice new tag. I suppose we can still wait and see a little bit if people will really use _Mathematica_ for this purpose though.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom gave me the opening to plug by [latest project](https://bobthechemist.com/2016/03/goiolink-release-candidate-1/) using a Raspberry Pi and Mathematica to collect data from Vernier sensors.